# Why does this check not work? and how can I make it work?

Tags: javascript

```
const snake = [[0,0],[1,1],[1,2]];
for (let i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++){
    randomiseFoodLocation();
}
function randomiseFoodLocation(){
    let x = 0
    let y = 0;
    for (let check = 0 ; check == 0;){
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2));
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2));
        for (let j = 0 ; j < snake.length ; j++){
            if (x!=snake[j][0] && y!=snake[j][1]){
                check++;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("Food Location = "+x+","+y);
}
console.log("snake = "+snake);
```

What I want to achieve is to
1 select random x and y coordinates on my grid which works
and
2 check if those coordinates are empty which doesn't

I also have a visual depiction of where the snake is on the grid and where the food is located I won't however I cannot post it here as it is required for code in posts to be limited to the absolute minimum required to show a proble which I would consieder to be the above as such I provide
1 a pastebin link to the source code of the full project https://pastebin.com/KaeEFh3M
2 a pastebin link to the source code of the display of the error https://pastebin.com/umm3g1m6

also I am aware of the fact that I'm checking the index 0 of snake which is equal to 0 yes starting the check from 1 does in fact result in having no food positions equal to any of the snake positions however it does also result in no positions anywhere along the y axis of the snake and stops working as soon as the snake starts moving around in the x axis

Comment: Text is much easier to read when you split it into phrases.

Comment: @trincot yeah I kind suck at that even in my native language

Comment: question would you guys prefer if I were to replace the pastebin links with snippets?

Comment: btw, no need to wrap numbers or empty else/block statements

Comment: @NinaScholz oh yeah the else was a leftover from some of the tests that I did should've deleted that

Answer (score 0):

Try `check = 1` instead of `check++`.

`check++` may not stop the loop.

I hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't as the problem is not that the loop isn't stopped it's that it's stopped even though the food positon doesnt meet the required criteria

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem but the answer wouldn't solve anybody elses problem I kinda just remembered that I've already made a system to detect if a specific spot is a snake or not So I just reused that as a patchy workaround I still have no Idea why does this not work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).